# oidc-client and Azure AD B2C: Bad Request

Tags: openid-connect, azure-ad-b2c, oidc-client-js

`oidc-client` returns the following error at `UserManager.userManager.signinRedirectCallback()`:

[image]

Here is my config:

```
  authority: 'https://<tenant_name>.b2clogin.com/<tenant_name>.onmicrosoft.com/<policy>/v2.0',
  client_id: '<client_id>',
  redirect_uri: `http://localhost:4200/login-callback`,
  response_type: 'code',
  scope: 'openid profile',
```

Also:

- Before the error, I am able to login properly using the Azure AD B2C login page.
- When I use the endpoint v1 (by removing the "v2.0" suffix from the authority) it's working as expected.
- I use the "Sign up and sign in" (no custom policy here).

Comment: Take a network trace (chrome dev tools or Fiddler) so we can see what the request looks like.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was not in my code, but in my B2C settings on Azure.
Thanks to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61272502/5960632) from @chrsi, I was able to fix it.

First, change the reply URL type in your app registration manifest to `Spa`:

[image]

Then, make sure you set some API specific scopes (e.g. `https://<tenant>.onmicrosoft.com/api/write`). Otherwise, the returned access token will be undefined.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to get the code by executing the following request in the browser,reference [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/openid-connect):

```
GET https://<tenant_name>.b2clogin.com/<tenant_name>.onmicrosoft.com/<policy>/oauth2/v2.0/authorize?
client_id=<client_id>
&response_type=code+id_token
&redirect_uri=https://jwt.ms
&response_mode=query
&scope=openid offline_access 
&state=123
&nonce=12345
```

[image]

Comment: The `oauth2/v2.0/authorize` request works it's the `oauth2/v2.0/token` request that is failling.